# What are the applications(uses) of Procedurally Generated Graphics other than video games?

Tags: graphics, procedural-generation

I understand that procedural graphics are widely used in video games and in the film industry to rapidly develop virtual worlds and randomizing various content within the game. Other than the game and film industry, does it have any application(use) elsewhere?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programing

Comment: +Close as this is not much about specific programing problem. Anyway I think is possibly used in science for generating random environments for biology or geology purposes.

Comment: I guess I'll take that as an answer. May I ask, which website may I pose such questions? Thank you.

Comment: hard to say may be some 3D graphic related site or computer science one ...